# Who invented/discovered the scalar potential?

Tags: potential

[This answer](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/5080/232) mentions Franz Ernst Neumann as the inventor of the vector potential, but who invented or discovered the scalar potential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lagrange (1736-1813) in 1777, followed by Laplace (1749-1827) in 1782, was the first to introduce the scalar gravitational potential.<sup>1</sup>

Lagrange's paper, *[Remarques générales sur lemouvement de plusieurs corps qui s'attirent mutuellement enraison inverse des carrés des distances](https://archive.org/stream/oeuvresdelagrang04lagr#page/396/mode/2up)*, was read at the Academy of Berlin on 20 October 1777.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>References
1. [Assis, André K. T.](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/) [*Relational Mechanics and Implementation of Mach’s Principle with Weber’s Gravitational Force*](https://www.ifi.unicamp.br/~assis/Relational-Mechanics-Mach-Weber.pdf). Montréal: Apeiron, 2014, p. 475.
2. [Duhem, Pierre Maurice Marie](https://www.encyclopedia.com/people/history/historians-miscellaneous-biographies/pierre-maurice-marie-duhem). [*Leçons sur l’électricité et le magnétisme*](https://archive.org/stream/leonssurllec01duheuoft#page/12/mode/2up). vol. 1. Paris: Gauthier-Villars, 1891, [p. 13](https://archive.org/stream/leonssurllec01duheuoft#page/12/mode/2up).</sup>

Comment: But the word itself was coined by George Green, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Yes, Green is the first to use the term in English, [according to the _OED_](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/148805?redirectedFrom=potential#eid29048465), in "G. Green _Ess. on Applic. Math. Anal. to Electr. & Magnetism_ 16."