# Introduction of magnetic vector potential

Tags: physics, electromagnetism, potential

Who first introduced the concept of magnetic vector potential and why?

Was it introduced only for ease of mathematical calculation or it was done  keeping in mind its physical significance like connection with momentum and all?

Comment: Your second question is not really meaningful.   How one parametrizes physical values and energy interactions (e.g. system Hamiltonian) is unrelated to what we might or might not call a "physical significance."

Answer (score 2):

It was the German mathematician F. E. Neumann.
I refer you to [this](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5078/who-discovered-the-magnetic-vector-potential-veca) discussion on the History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange, where you will find your answers in detail.